# Running Excel Scripts on Outlook Attachments then sending processed files

Tags: power-automate, rpa

TL;DR: I want to extract an Excel attachment from an Outlook message, automate an Excel script on the unprocessed reports, and then send the output in a new email message.

1. I have reports from Amazon that I have sent to a specific email on my Outlook folder each month.
2. I set up Power Automate to trigger whenever an email with an attachment is received in this folder.
3. I want to take the attachment in this Outlook email and run an Excel script that I build on Excel Desktop (not an Excel application macro) to format the data.
4. And then I want to send the output/result (scripted email attachment) as the body of an email out to clients.

I've gotten the first and last parts to run, but I can't get the script to process the file, that's the phase that always breaks that automation.

[image]

Things that I think might be causing the issue:

- Do I need to extract the attachment from the email and save it as a file before I can run the Excel script on it?
- Does the attachment need to be saved through Share Point to be later referenced by the Excel script?
- Does the script need to be on the same or different cards as previous steps?

I've seen people run the Excel script through a Scope.
I've also looked at every available YouTube video to troubleshoot this: some go over certain steps in the process, but I'm having a hard time threading everything together.

**Other Things I've Tried**

I also tried to build a macro that does the same thing as my Excel desktop automation, and then wrote VBA code so each time a new sheet is opened the same macro is run, processing the data. But I couldn't get it to run on any new future sheet that I open, even when writing the VBA auto-open code in Module as well as This Worksheet.

I'm open to any method that will make this work.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

[image: Total Workflow]

Get email (V2) - Message ID

```
@{triggerOutputs()?['body/id']}
```

Apply to Each - Select an output from previous steps

```
@{outputs('Get_email_(V2)')?['body/attachments']}
```

Create File - File Name

```
@{items('Apply_to_each')?['name']}
```

Create File - File Content

```
@{items('Apply_to_each')?['contentBytes']}
```

Move or rename a file - File (make sure you add .xlsx for Destination File Path)

```
@outputs('Create_file')?['body/Id']
```

Run Script - File

```
@outputs('Move_or_rename_a_file')?['body/Id']
```

Get file content - File

```
@outputs('Move_or_rename_a_file')?['body/Id']
```

Send an email (V2) - Attachments Name-1

```
@outputs('Move_or_rename_a_file')?['body/DisplayName']
```

Send an email (V2) - Attachments Content - 1

```
@body('Get_file_content')?['body']
```